# How to read .txt tables into R

Tags: r

I have a .txt file which I think was output from STATA, but I'm not sure. It is a list of tables formatted like this:

```
         Q1 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
     answer |         35       21.08       21.08
       text |          4        2.41       23.49
      words |         35       21.08       44.5
  something |         38       22.89       67.47
       blah |         54       32.53      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        166      100.00

               Q2 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------------+-----------------------------------
              foo |          1        0.60        0.60
         blahblah |         11        6.63        7.23
              etc |         26       15.66       22.89
        more text |         82       49.40       72.29
           answer |          7        4.22       76.51
  survey response |         39       23.49      100.00
------------------+-----------------------------------
            Total |        166      100.00

         Q3 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
     option |          7        4.22        4.22
       text |         24       14.46       18.67
      blahb |         25       15.06       33.73
  more text |         82       49.40       83.13
        etc |         28       16.87      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |        166      100.00
```

It continues for about 200 questions and their respective survey answers. Does anyone know how I can quickly read each survey question into separate data frames in R?

Comment: You can take a look at `scan`. With a little counting and maybe a bit of `grep`, you can probably construct some re-useable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for `scan()`:

```
txt <- "         Q1 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
answer |         35       21.08       21.08
text |          4        2.41       23.49
words |         35       21.08       44.5
something |         38       22.89       67.47
blah |         54       32.53      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
Total |        166      100.00

Q2 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------------+-----------------------------------
foo |          1        0.60        0.60
blahblah |         11        6.63        7.23
etc |         26       15.66       22.89
more text |         82       49.40       72.29
answer |          7        4.22       76.51
survey response |         39       23.49      100.00
------------------+-----------------------------------
Total |        166      100.00

Q3 |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
option |          7        4.22        4.22
text |         24       14.46       18.67
blahb |         25       15.06       33.73
more text |         82       49.40       83.13
etc |         28       16.87      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
Total |        166      100.00"


library(purrr)
```

You can just as easily read from a file vs the above text vector. The main goal here is to remove cruft from the data and get it into a form we can work with, so we get rid of the dashed lines and the `Total` line, and convert spaces to commas. This makes a big assumption about your data format so it needs to be consistent.

```
readLines(textConnection(txt)) %>% 
  discard(~grepl("(----|Total)", .)) %>% 
  gsub("[[:space:]]*\\|[[:space:]]*", ",", .) %>% 
  gsub("[[:space:]][[:space:]]+", ",", .) %>% 
  gsub("^,", "", .) -> lines
```

There's a blank line between the tables. This is another assumption the code makes. We find that blank line and extract the lines that are between blanks (including the start and end of the text). Then we read that into a data frame with `read.csv`.

```
starts <- c(1, which(lines=="")+1)
ends <- c(which(lines=="")-1, length(lines))

map2(starts, ends, function(start, end) {
  read.csv(textConnection(lines[start:end]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})
```

This results in a list of data frames:

```
## [[1]]
##          Q1 Freq. Percent   Cum.
## 1    answer    35   21.08  21.08
## 2      text     4    2.41  23.49
## 3     words    35   21.08  44.50
## 4 something    38   22.89  67.47
## 5      blah    54   32.53 100.00
## 
## [[2]]
##                Q2 Freq. Percent   Cum.
## 1             foo     1    0.60   0.60
## 2        blahblah    11    6.63   7.23
## 3             etc    26   15.66  22.89
## 4       more text    82   49.40  72.29
## 5          answer     7    4.22  76.51
## 6 survey response    39   23.49 100.00
## 
## [[3]]
##          Q3 Freq. Percent   Cum.
## 1    option     7    4.22   4.22
## 2      text    24   14.46  18.67
## 3     blahb    25   15.06  33.73
## 4 more text    82   49.40  83.13
## 5       etc    28   16.87 100.00
```

But, I think this might be more useful as one big data frame:

```
map2_df(starts, ends, function(start, end) {

  df <- read.csv(textConnection(lines[start:end]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

  colnames(df) %>% 
    tolower() %>% 
    gsub("\\.", "", .) -> cols

  question <- cols[1]
  cols[1] <- "text"

  setNames(df, cols) %>% 
    mutate(question=question) %>% 
    mutate(n=1:nrow(.)) %>% 
    select(question, n, text, freq, percent, cum) %>%
    mutate(percent=percent/100, cum=cum/100)

})
##   question n            text freq percent    cum
## 1        q1 1          answer   35  0.2108 0.2108
## 2        q1 2            text    4  0.0241 0.2349
## 3        q1 3           words   35  0.2108 0.4450
## 4        q1 4       something   38  0.2289 0.6747
## 5        q1 5            blah   54  0.3253 1.0000
## 6        q2 1             foo    1  0.0060 0.0060
## 7        q2 2        blahblah   11  0.0663 0.0723
## 8        q2 3             etc   26  0.1566 0.2289
## 9        q2 4       more text   82  0.4940 0.7229
## 10       q2 5          answer    7  0.0422 0.7651
## 11       q2 6 survey response   39  0.2349 1.0000
## 12       q3 1          option    7  0.0422 0.0422
## 13       q3 2            text   24  0.1446 0.1867
## 14       q3 3           blahb   25  0.1506 0.3373
## 15       q3 4       more text   82  0.4940 0.8313
## 16       q3 5             etc   28  0.1687 1.0000
```